# Resultset in java is not working according to my expectations

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
dbStatement = con.createStatement();
dbResult = dbStatement.executeQuery("SELECT Vendor_Code FROM temp ORDER BY status ASC ");

while (dbResult.next())
{
    VendorCode=dbResult.getString("Vendor_Code");
    System.out.println(VendorCode);

    dbStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('"+VendorCode+"')");
}
```

In the above code I am selecting a list of vendor code in the ascending order of their status,it works properly if I don't add:

```
dbStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('"+VendorCode+"')");
```

into the `while` loop. If I add this I'm getting result as only the first value which is in the sorted list and also it's getting inserted into the temp1 table...

I am using Java swing and MySQL in NetBeans. Any idea please why this is happening?

If I do the above code in other way as,

```
    dbStatement = con.createStatement();
    dbInsert = con.createStatement();
    dbResult = dbStatement.executeQuery("SELECT Vendor_Code FROM temp ORDER BY               status ASC ");

     while (dbResult.next())
             {
                 VendorCode=dbResult.getString("Vendor_Code");


                dbResult = dbInsert.executeQuery("SELECT Bid_No,Vendor_Name,Vendor_Address,Amount,Tax_Percentage,Amount_Aftertax,Expected_Deliverydate,Vendor_Code FROM purchase_bid    where   PE_Number='"+penumber+"' AND Vendor_Code='"+VendorCode+"'  ");


                 while(dbResult.next())

                    {


                      Bid_Number=dbResult.getString("Bid_No");
                      vendor_name=dbResult.getString("Vendor_Name");
                      vendor_address=dbResult.getString("Vendor_Address");
                      Amount=dbResult.getString("Amount");
                      tax=dbResult.getString("Tax_Percentage");
                      date2=dbResult.getString("Expected_Deliverydate");
                      Amount_Aftertax=dbResult.getString("Amount_Aftertax");
                      venCode=dbResult.getString("Vendor_Code");
                      date3=date2.split("-");
                        String day="";
                        String month="";
                        String year="";
                        day=date3[2];
                        month=date3[1];
                        year=date3[0];

                     date=day+"-"+month+"-"+year;
                      addtoCart();//for displaying it in jTable


                   }


              }
```

It does not take VendorCode in ascending order for retrieving values from purchase_bid table..Then it again takes first sorted value and nothing is displayed in jTable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use the statement instance for one operation. So calling the executeUpdate-method erases the ResultSet obtained by the executeQuery-method.

Create a second statement, so that:

```
dbStatement = con.createStatement();
dbInsert = con.createStatement();
dbResult = dbStatement.executeQuery("SELECT Vendor_Code FROM temp ORDER BY status ASC ");

while (dbResult.next())
{
    VendorCode=dbResult.getString("Vendor_Code");
    System.out.println(VendorCode);

    dbInsert.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('"+VendorCode+"')");
}
```

If you're not just testing and you actually want to bulk insert the Vendor_Code from temp to temp1, try using INSERT ... SELECT

```
dbInsert = con.createStatement();
dbInsert.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO temp1 SELECT Vendor_Code FROM temp");
```

See the official MySQL documentation for further details on this type of INSERT:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @Jules...You are right..now it's working..thank you..So can we add as many Statement variables as according to our need..right?

Comment: I don't know of any definitive limits, but I'm sure there are some, such as number of concurrent DB connections from one user or, well, heap memory. Also be aware of transactional implications and race conditions.
When you encapsulate your DB queries, you might find yourself able to reuse certain statement instances, e.g. as a class member. Quite often you see one statement instance used for reading operations and one for writing operations. You might also want to look into parametrising your queries and ORM frameworks...

Comment: Ok..can you please check the addition in my question??

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing there, but I don't think you do either :) But it looks like you're trying to do a JOIN without SQL :) You shouldn't have a nested loop through the same resultset, you'll end up skipping the first loop as the ResultSet cursor moves on and again, you're overwriting your first ResultSet with a different set. This will never work. Do you understand at all how variables, references, object instances and variable scopes work?

Answer (score 7):

You can only use one result set per statement at a time (for a query, update etc.). See [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time

I would either:

1. load all your vendor codes into a collection, and then perform an update using a new statement/update
2. perform all the required actions within one SQL update statement (may be preferable for performance and transactional reasons. All the work will be contained in the database instance)

**EDIT:** Amended following EJP's comment below.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the code option 2 seems like the better choice all round. If they're not doing anything else with the returned results (which seems to be the case), then there's no reason to return them at all.

Comment: Not correct. It can be used as many times as necessary. However: 'only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists'[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).

Comment: @EJP - yes. I'd just come to that conclusion myself after some Googling. I shall amend appropriately

Comment: I did it in this way also,but it's not working at all...
    dbStatement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES (SELECT Vendor_Code FROM temp ORDER BY status ASC)");
}